# Implicit instantiation of template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I'm designing a class template `Monad`, which is parameterized by a template type. For example, there can be `Monad<std::vector>`, `Monad<std::shared_ptr>`, etc.

I have this utility `struct` that can be used to extract the container type of a higher-kinded type (e.g. extract `std::vector` from a `std::vector<int>`):

```
template<typename>
struct FType;

template<typename A>
struct FType<std::vector<A>> {
    template<typename B>
    using type = std::vector<B>;
};

// FType<std::vector<int>>::type == std::vector
```

Now for `Monad`:

```
template<template <typename...> class F>
struct Monad;

template<>
struct Monad<std::vector> {

    /*
     * Example parameters:
     *   FA: std::vector<int>
     *   F:  std::vector
     *   M:  Monad<std::vector>
     */
    template<typename FA,
             template <typename...> class F = FType<FA>::template type,
             typename M = Monad<F>>
    static void foo(const FA &)
    {
        M::bark();
    }

    static void bark()
    {
        std::cout << "Woof!\n";
    }
};
```

I'm trying to have `Monad::foo` automatically infer its template parameters. So instead of doing:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};

// This works
Monad<std::vector>::foo<
    std::vector<int>,   // FA
    std::vector,        // F
    Monad<std::vector>  // M
>(v);

// This also works
Monad<std::vector>::foo<
    std::vector<int>,   // FA
    std::vector         // F
>(v);
```

I want to be able to do:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};

// This does not compile
Monad<std::vector>::foo(v);

// Neither does this
Monad<std::vector>::foo<
    std::vector<int>  // FA
>(v);
```

The error I got (for both not-compiling examples) was:

```
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'Monad<type>'
        M::bark();
        ^

template is declared here
struct Monad;
       ^

error: incomplete definition of type 'Monad<type>'
        M::bark();
        ~^~
```

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE:** As Sam has pointed out, `std::vector`, `FType<std::vector<Something>>::type`, and `FType<std::vector<SomethingElse>>::type` are all different! (Although for a specific `A`, `std::is_same` shows that `std::vector<A>`, `FType<std::vector<Something>>::type<A>`, and `FType<std::vector<SomethingElse>>::type<A>` are the same.) If I specialize `Monad<FType<std::vector<int>>::type>`, then things work out...but clearly this is not desirable... Is there any other way to implement `FType`?

**UPDATE 2:** Changing `FType` to this:

```
template<typename... A>
struct FType<std::vector<A...>> {
    template<typename... B>
    using type = std::vector<B...>;
};
```

has no effect.

Comment: The "this works" part doesn't really work for gcc: "template argument deduction/substitution failed: t.C:48:6: note:   cannot convert ‘v’ (type ‘std::vector<int>’) to type ‘std::vector<int>&&’" -- so you're already behind the 8-ball, coming out of the gate.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm using `-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`, and both g++ 4.8/4.9/5.3 and clang++ shipped with Xcode 7.3 can compile it (on OS X). Maybe you were not using C++11?

Comment: If your comment is directed at me, I'm using gcc 5.3.1 in c++11 mode. Newer versions of gcc are much more strict when it comes to enforcing C++. Additionally: the Monad specialization takes a `std::vector` as a parameter. That doesn't match up with what Ftype...::type results in. I don't think this will work.

Comment: In order to make the "this works" version to compile, I have to pass std::move(v) as a parameter to foo. Which makes sense.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ah I see, that was actually a typo, sorry about that! I'll correct `foo`'s signature. Regarding your additional comment, `Ftype<FA>::type` itself is not a full type, it's also a template type. Why would it not work?

Comment: I believe because for the "this works" case, F is, explicitly, as a `std::vector`. For the non working case, you resolve F as, basically `template<typename B> class std::vector`. The two are not the same.

Comment: Remember that `std::vector` has more than one parameter - you're just allowing the 2nd to be defaulted. This should probably affect `FType::type`

Comment: @Useless I've updated `FType`, but it still doesn't work. See update above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why it doesn't work

The problem is when you explicitly provide `std::vector` for `F`, `F` is actually `std::vector`. But when you allow it to be deduced, it gets deduced as `FType<A>::type` - which is *not* `std::vector`. It's deducible as such, but it isn't the same.

#### How to fix it

You don't actually... need any of this extra machinery for this particular problem right? You can just deduce the argument to `foo` as an instance of a template template:

```
template <template <typename...> class F, typename... Args>
static void foo(F<Args...> const& ) {
    using M = Monad<F>; 
    M::bark();
}
```

More generally, you can just go from `FA` to the monad in a single step:

```
template <class FA>
struct as_monad;

template <class FA>
using as_monad_t = typename as_monad<FA>::type;

template <template <typename...> class F, typename... Args>
struct as_monad<F<Args...>> {
    using type = Monad<F>;
};
```

And then:

```
template <class FA>
static void foo(FA const& ) {
    using M = as_monad_t<FA>; 
    M::bark();
}
```

Comment: The actual problem is more complicated. Basically I have a type `F<A>` (`std::vector<int>`, for example), a callable type `Fn`, and `std::result_of<Fn(A)>::type` gives a `G<B>` (which I get back as a whole, `GB`). The problem is I can't separate the `G` from `GB`; I need the `G` to find the specialized `Monad` implementation.

Comment: @ZizhengTai Just go in one step via a type trait

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I want!