# Get "implicit instantiation of undefined template" when trying to combine type traits and CRTP

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, crtp

This is a base `Repository` class interface, which has a `iterator()` method. Just like the design pattern URL, the `Repository` classes and `Iterator` class are both polymorphism. Instead of virtual function and pimpl, i choose to use CRTP here.

```cpp
template <typename Impl>
struct RepositoryTraits;

template <typename Impl>
class Repository{
public:
  template<typename ConcreteIterType>
  struct Iterator{
    int next(){
        return static_cast<ConcreteIterType*>(this)->next();
    }
  };
  
  Iterator<typename RepositoryTraits<Impl>::IteratorType> iterator(){
    return static_cast<Impl*>(this)->iterator();
  }
};
```

Inspired by this wonderful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6006629/8510613). I try to use a trait helper to retrieve the actual `IterType` From derived `Repository` class instead of add another template parameter in the `Repository`'s template parameter list:

```cpp
class RepositoryImpl : public Repository<RepositoryImpl>{
public:
  struct RealIterator : public Iterator<RealIterator>{
      int next(){
          return 1;
      }
  };
  using IteratorType = RealIterator;

  RealIterator iterator(){
      return RealIterator();
  }
};

template <>
struct RepositoryTraits<RepositoryImpl> {
    using IteratorType = RepositoryImpl::IteratorType;
};
```

Of course, the above code cannot [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/sYMP3q44f). The compiler hint me "implicit instantiation of undefined template 'RepositoryTraits"

I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476323/implicit-instantiation-of-template-specialization), but i cannot learn from it. What is the correct way to combine CRTP and type traits here? Or should i use a better design? Any help will be appreciated.

---

I've found some trait based answers, like http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/266019/ or [C++ static polymorphism (CRTP) and using typedefs from derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006614/c-static-polymorphism-crtp-and-using-typedefs-from-derived-classes). But I cannot figure out why it can succeed in these case while not in mine.

---

I've tried to directly return a `T` and use SFINAE to restrict its type in the base class like below. The code cannot work either, since it force the caller to provide a `T` for the call of `iterator()`.

Changing `iterator` to `auto` deduction return type can work. However, i still want to use SFINAE to fix the `Iterator` type in subclass. How can this be done?

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Impl>
class Repository{
public:
  template<typename ConcreteIterType>
  struct Iterator{
    int next(){
        return static_cast<ConcreteIterType*>(this)->next();
    }
  };
  template <typename T>
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Iterator<T>, T>::value, T> iterator(){
    return static_cast<Impl*>(this)->iterator();
  }
};

class RepositoryImpl : public Repository<RepositoryImpl>{
public:
  struct RealIterator : public Iterator<RealIterator>{
      int next(){
          return 1;
      }
  };
  using IteratorType = RealIterator;

  RealIterator iterator(){
      return RealIterator();
  }
};
```

Comment: @user17732522 I want to let the base CRTP interface implementation of ```iterator()``` return derived class's corresponding iterator type, and directly use ```RepositoryImpl::IteratorType``` seems invalid, and i imitate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006614/c-static-polymorphism-crtp-and-using-typedefs-from-derived-classes/6006629#6006629) answer to use the trait class to retrieve ```IteratorType``` from derived class(but fail)

Comment: @user17732522 thanks for your help again. I wonder if is there any solution other than passing another template parameter to the CRTP base, or like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113878/c-crtp-and-accessing-deriveds-nested-typedefs-from-base, use SFINAE to restrict the type?

Answer (score 1):

The traits specialization is not supposed to rely on the definition of the implementation class, but yours does to access `RepositoryImpl::IteratorType`.

To resolve this, you could move the iterator type into the trait instead. The implementation class can then use the iterator from the traits specialization. Additionally, because your implementation class is not a template, the order of the declarations needs to be fixed:

```
template <typename Impl>
struct RepositoryTraits;

template <typename Impl>
class Repository {
   public:
    template <typename ConcreteIterType>
    struct Iterator {};

    Iterator<typename RepositoryTraits<Impl>::IteratorType> iterator();
};

class RepositoryImpl;

template <>
struct RepositoryTraits<RepositoryImpl> {
    struct IteratorType
        : public Repository<RepositoryImpl>::Iterator<IteratorType> {};
};

class RepositoryImpl : public Repository<RepositoryImpl> {
   public:
    using IteratorType = RepositoryTraits<RepositoryImpl>::IteratorType;
    Iterator<IteratorType> iterator();
};
```

Note however that this still has an issue: `RepositoryTraits<RepositoryImpl>` instantiates `Repository<RepositoryImpl>`, which requires lookup of `RepositoryTraits<Impl>::IteratorType` with `Impl = RepositoryImpl`. However, the point of instantiation of `Repository<RepositoryImpl>` will be before the definition of `RepositoryTraits<RepositoryImpl>`, so technically that should fail.

However, there is an open issue with the standard regarding this ([CWG 287](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#287)) and currently compilers seem to follow the suggested fix of the issue, which makes it so the required name lookup can find all members of `RepositoryTraits<RepositoryImpl>` which were declared before the point at which instantiation of the specialization `Repository<RepositoryImpl>` is required.

If you want to avoid this issue as well, I suppose it would be easier to move the iterator types into the namespace scope instead of using nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution target at the whole design, which eliminating the whole `Iterator` type and use implicit interface dependency like STL way:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Impl>
class Repository{
public:
  using IteratorWrappedType = int;

  auto iterator(){
    return static_cast<Impl*>(this)->iterator();
  }
};

class RepositoryImpl : public Repository<RepositoryImpl>{
public:
  struct RealIterator{
      IteratorWrappedType next(){
          return 2;
      }
  };

  RealIterator iterator(){
      return RealIterator();
  }
};

template <typename T>
int foo(Repository<T>* repo){
    auto it = repo->iterator();
    return it.next();
}

int main(){
    RepositoryImpl repo;
    std::cout << foo(&repo) << std::endl;
}
```

I posted this to consider this a prompt for an open thread, whether this is a better design or not.